# Any way to catch ACTION_UP in a view that did not intercept ACTION_DOWN?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a drag-drop functionality for pre-honeycomb devices. I'd like to touch an item in one frame layout, drag it over another frame layout, and have the second frame see the ACTION_UP event. Unfortunately haven't found a way to do that, it seems only the view hierarchy that saw the original ACTION_DOWN gets notified of the ACTION_UP.

I've got the drag part working, but when I release my finger, the view underneath the ACTION_UP gets no notification at all. Is there any way to workaround this?

Comment: i think it's impossible. the action down on frame 1, and the action up on frame 1, it didn't action up on frame 2, except you action down on frame 2, but before this you need up on frame1 and down to frame2, or your another finger to down on the frame2.

Comment: It is a little tricky but possible, if you know that you can intercept all touch events in the [`Activity.dispatchTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up working around this by intercepting all of the events in the frame view with `onInterceptTouchEvent`